# WiFi range dropped in Windows 7 and Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, wireless-networking, router

I had Windows 10, then 1 day my wifi range dropped. It shows only one signal when I'm on the same floor of the router, and no signal found when even go out of the door. For many other reasons (and for this one too) I switch from Windows 10 to Windows 7. But the problem is same. I tried to update the drivers but nothing happened.

It also sometimes shows `Limited Access` and a yellow triangle on network indicator, but all the other devices connected via that network (wired AWA wireless) showing `Internet Access` and also fine range. So it may not be the problem of the router. I can't even open the router page (192.168.0.1) when `Limited Access` shown. So I think It's not the internet, but the router is not connected to my system.

Here's my WIFIcard:
`Realtek RTL8723BE 802.11 bgn Wifi Adapter`

What I do is troubleshoot the problem and after waiting 10-18 seconds my internet came back.

**Is it my system's hardware problem or something else? Can I resolve this thing?**

Comment: Have you restarted the router?

Comment: Yeah, several times.

Comment: Have you reset the routers configuration?

Comment: No, it's working well in all the others devices. So I think reconfiguration will not work out.

Comment: What made you think this was caused by or related to the version of Windows on your computer? Wireless range is nearly entirely based on the hardware, either the network router or the wireless radio inside your computer.

Comment: This range issue was in earlier windows 10, as it happened with my 2-3 friends and asked by many users on windows forum. And I also had the issue, which is resolved by installing the new windows updates. But something happened again which is not resolved even after changing the windiows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I list below some operations which might help.
As there are many possibilities, it is best to try them sequentially, undoing
the ones which didn't help.

1. Go to Activity Center (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and turn off `Location`.
2. Update your network adapter drivers (let us know its model if you wish us to
   verify the driver).
3. Ensure that the Windows 10 driver is installed by running Device Manager,
   right-click on your wireless adapter and choose `Uninstall`, then reboot.
4. Set the wireless adapter to work in maximum performance mode by in
   Control Panel / Power Options, locate your current plan and click
   `Change plan settings`, click on `Change advanced power settings`,
   locate `Wireless Adapter Settings` and set the `Power Saving Mode` to `Maximum Performance`, finally click `Apply` and `OK`.
   Or, alternatively, you can just switch to `High performance mode` in Power Options.
5. Change the Sensibility value by in Device Manager, right-click on your wireless adapter and choose `Properties`, then in the
   `Advanced` tab:

   - Locate `Roaming Sensitivity Level`, `Roaming Aggressiveness`
     or `Roam Tendency` and set it to `Highest` or `Aggressive`.
   - Set `Transmit Power` or `Transmit Power Level` to `Highest`
   - Set `Antenna Diversity` to `Auto`
   - In `Band Preference` choose `Prefer 802.11a` if your wireless network
     is using 5GHz, or to `Prefer 802.11g/b` if using 2.4GHz.
   - In some cases, setting `Antenna diversity` to `Auxiliary` solved the
     problem.
   - Save changes and restart the computer.
6. Disabling the Bluetooth adapter sometimes fixes WiFi range problems.
7. Update your router firmware.
8. Change the router frequency to 5GHz may encounter less interference
   (if supported).

Comment: I currently have windows 7 installed in my system.

Comment: Most of the above points are also applicable to Windows 7. Point 1 notably does not apply. There is no way to know if they apply to your problem without trying.

Comment: I am little confused in step 3, do I have to uninstall my `network adapter wireless drivers`?

Comment: Thanks for your time @harrymc. I  have done all the steps you mentioned above except step 3. But it didn't help. I've already updated my firmware in step 7. I've done all steps serially. But still negative results.

Comment: For point 3 you can see an example [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Reinstall-Wireless-Drivers). Ignore the parts of the article that don't apply.

Comment: It's done. 3rd step did my job. Thanks a lot @harrymc  :)

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified what model WIFI card you are using, but it could very well be a WIFI driver issue - particularly if you are using a Realtek card.

Despite what others say, drivers can make a huge difference to WIFI performance.  This is a well known issue with Linux - where its very common to install an OS and get the kind of abysmal WIFI performance you describe, and everything starts working correctly when you remove the old driver and use the correct one.  (The same issue happens on Windows, as per [this](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN292007/slow-network-performance-with-the-realtek-network-controller-installed-on-the-optiplex-3010-sff-desktop-computer?lang=EN) link)

Another [interesting link](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Realtek-RTL8188CE-802-11b-g-n-WiFi-Adapter-Poor-Performance/td-p/5200190) shows an RTL8188CE WIFI adaptor having problems with Windows 10 by getting into a low power state after going in to sleep mode.

Comment: I have `Realtek RTL8723BE 802.11 bgn Wifi Adapter`, I've edited and mentioned it in my question too.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks for your help. But I have to mark @harrymc's answer as accepted answer, as he gave the same solution before you in step 3 of his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the wifi range limitation problem on my Acer v3-471 with Windows 7.

I used Ubuntu try for internet access. With Ubuntu there was no range limitation or speed problem. I installed number of drivers from Acer and Atheros sites for Windows 7 but problems remained same.

When I google the problem I found a [link](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2794501/decreased-wifi-range-windows-update.html) where Mr.Kahlo kahlow said I might find a disconnected antenna connector of my wifi card.

After reconnecting the antenna the problem is solved.

Comment: So your answer is ‘‘I found a disconnected antenna connector of my Wi-Fi card, based on suggestion of Kahlo kahlow at [link]; after reconnecting the antenna, problem solved.’’? Is there anything else in your post that’s useful for people to know?

Comment: The main thing is, it works with Ubuntu even antenna has been disconnected. Then we are misled as hardware has no errors.